# How to find the extracted file path in linux(CentOs 6.7)?

Tags: linux, hadoop, hbase

We are using stand alone mode in creating Hbase table using JAVA API. For that I need to give the path of the extracted file in the profile page( usually we give it some variables after installing JDk , the same way). Am stuck in giving the path of Hbase so only the code is not getting the permission of Zookeeper to enter the Hbase. So please suggest how to get the path of Hbase file.

Comment: For example , Hbase-1.2.0.tar.gz after extracting it will be like Hbase-1.2.0... I need to get the path of this file to place in the path.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Try `sudo find / -name '*hbase*'`